# Is the F# interactive app open source?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

How would I include the fsi REPL in my application for scripting?

The [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases) doesn't appear to have anything for that.

Comment: Yes, it is. Its source is on GitHub: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/src/fsharp/fsi

Comment: not sure why this would be on hold, where else would I ask this question?

Comment: Another alternative to the link given by Ramon is [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service), which exposes additional functionality deemed needed in scenarios like yours.

Comment: I don't think the question should have been put on hold, but maybe a better question would have been to simply ask how to expose the repl in your application.

Comment: The Codeplex drop does indeed include FSI: http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#compiler/3.1/Nov2013/src/fsharp/fsi/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed open-source, and its source is available from multiple sources:

1. [GitHub F# Compiler & Standard Library repository](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/src/fsharp/fsi)
2. [GitHub F# Compiler Service repository](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service)
3. [CodePlex F# PowerPack & Code Drops repository](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#compiler/3.1/Nov2013/src/fsharp/fsi/)

Answer (score 4):

One way would be learning the sources of FSI available from few repositories mentioned in the comments to the question and then somehow exposing its functionality to your application by modifying the sources (changing visibility, etc). This way apparently is steep and painful.

Fortunately, some work in this direction has been already done along the lines of  [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service), so another way may be embedding FSI into your application as a standardized service. Few details upon embedding FSI as a service are available in the following [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/skillsmatter/progressive-f-tutorials-nyc-don-syme-tomas-petricek-on-calling-and-extending-the-f-compiler) given by Don Syme and Tomas Petricek during NYC 2013 SkillMatters days.

The presentation provides a link to (experimental) implementation of FSI service within `Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell` namespace, so the embedding may be as easy as in the snippet below:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell
.....
let fsi = FsiEvaluationSession([| "fsi.exe"; "--noninteractive"|], inStream, outStream, errStream)
.....
match fsi.EvalExpression(codeLines) with
    | Some value -> value.ReflectionValue
    | None -> raise (System.ArgumentException("fsi cannot evaluate expression"))
```

Comment: The code for this has not made it to the FSharp.Compiler.Service yet (AFAIK), but it is available in my local branch: https://github.com/tpetricek/fsharp/tree/fs-extend. See InteractiveService sample too: https://github.com/tpetricek/fsharp/tree/fs-extend/samples/InteractiveService